# Setting border-radius of input buttom

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i try to set border-radius: 14px to the textarea. it shows (missing attribute name).

```
<input id="txtDateRange" type="text" name="daterange" value="" style="width:80% "; "border-radius: 14px";  class="PrintHide" />
```

How i can do it in good way?
I have searched but could not find what i need.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

your syntax is not right.

```
<input id="txtDateRange" type="text" name="daterange" value="" style="width:80%;border-radius: 14px;"  class="PrintHide" />
```

Comment: you can read more about styles here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style.asp. you can accept my answer too. thnx